# Local Data in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to have a "Login" form where a user would enter in a number that uniquely identifies them. After this number is entered I want all of the other forms to use that number on this local instance of the application. IE the user is "Logged In".

One solution would be to have a column in the list of users mark whether that user is the "Active" user, and have every form look up that field. This stops working when you want to have multiple people using the front end to access the same back end, as there would now be more than one "Active" user. Is there a way to make a global local variable that I can use to keep track of who is currently using this particular instance of the front end?

Comment: For reliable multi-user access each user **must** have their own local copy of the front-end regardless, so you could just save their ID number in a global variable or a local table in the front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reliable multi-user access each user **must** have their own local copy of the front-end regardless, so you could just save their ID number in a global variable or a local table in the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a public function in a module that returns the ID (stored in the module) and call it in queries and form modules.

Note that variables are always stored per process in the RAM and are therefore always per-user.